# How can I add Country and State dropdown in Custom admin form?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, country-regions

> I want to add country and state drop down in custom admin form.

**How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This Code into your Form**

> **In UI- Component**

```
<field name="country_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="region">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

> **Using Block**

```
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    
    protected $_systemStore;

    protected $_countryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {   
        $regioncode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');    

        $isElementDisabled = false;

            
        $optionsc=$this->_countryFactory->toOptionArray();

        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);

        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');

            if (!$model->getId()) 
            {
                $model->setData('is_active', $isElementDisabled ? '0' : '1');
            }

        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'edit_form',
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                            'method' => 'post'
                        ]
            ]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('storelocation_');

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit Store Location General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);

            $region_value = $model->getData('region');

        } else {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Location General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );

            $region_value = NULL;
        }

        $optionsc=$this->_countryFactory->toOptionArray();

        $country =  $fieldset->addField(
            'country',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'country',
                'label' => __('Country'),
                'id' => 'country',
                'title' => __('Country'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'values' => $optionsc,
                'required'  => true,
            ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
            'region',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'region',
                'label' => __('Region'),
                'id' => 'region',
                'title' => __('Region'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'values' =>['--Please Select Country--'],
                'required'  => true,
            ]
        );
  
    /* for add java script for country and region select */

        $country->setAfterElementHtml("   
    
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($) {

                    // on intial check whether country code exit or not 
                        
                   $(window).on('load', function() {

                    var country = $('#storelocation_country').val();
                    //var region = $('#storelocation_region').val();

                    var region = '".$region_value."';



                        //alert('region '+region+' country '+country);

                        $.ajax({
                               url : '". $this->getUrl('*/*/regionlist') . "country/' + $('#storelocation_country').val()+'/region/'+region,
                               type: 'get',
                               dataType: 'json',
                               showLoader:true,
                               success: function(data){
                                    $('#storelocation_region').empty();
                                    $('#storelocation_region').append(data.htmlconent);
                               }
                            });



                    });   

                    // onchange country this function called 

                   $(document).on('change', '#storelocation_country', function(event){

                    var country = $('#storelocation_country').val();

                    //alert(country);

                        $.ajax({
                               url : '". $this->getUrl('*/*/regionlist') . "country/' + $('#storelocation_country').val(),
                               type: 'get',
                               dataType: 'json',
                               showLoader:true,
                               success: function(data){
                                    $('#storelocation_region').empty();
                                    $('#storelocation_region').append(data.htmlconent);
                               }
                            });
                   })
                }

            );
            </script>"
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> **Add This File which get your region accourding to country name**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\YourAdminCoontroller;

class Regionlist extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_countryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $countrycode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('country');

        $regioncode = $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');

        if($regioncode == NULL){
            $regioncode='';
        }

        $selected = '';

        $state = "<option value=''>--Please Select--</option>";
        if ($countrycode != '') {
            $statearray =$this->_countryFactory->create()->setId(
                    $countrycode
                )->getLoadedRegionCollection()->toOptionArray();
            foreach ($statearray as $_state) {
                if($_state['value']){

                        if($regioncode == $_state['label']) { $selected = 'selected'; } else{  $selected = ''; }

                    $state .= "<option value='".$_state['label']."'  ".$selected." >" .$_state['label']. "</option>";
            }
           }
        }
        $result['htmlconent']=$state;
         $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
    }
  }
```

Comment: working fine but when there is no state and textbox value saved it is not showing saved value in form textbox